# Angular 7+, Is it good to call child component's method from parent?

Tags: angular, angular7

Sometimes I want to call the child component's method from the parent component, or somehow notify the child (from the parent) to call something.

**1st (call child component's method from parent):**

```
// CHILD
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<p>child</p>'
})

class ChildComponent {

  doSomething() {
    console.log('I am from child')
  }

}

// PARENT
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '<child-component></child-component>',
})

class ParentComponent{

  @ViewChild(ChildComponent ) child: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.child.doSomething();
  }
}
```

**2nd (Notify child component to call something):**

```
//CHILD
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() notify: Subject<boolean>;

  ngOnInit(){
     this.notify.subscribe(v => { 
        console.log("I am from child");
     });
  }

}

//PARENT
export class ParentComp {

    notify: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

    notifyChild(){
        this.notify.next(true);
    }

}
```

Here goes my questions:

1) What are the cons and pros of the 1st method? also if you are calling the child's method from a parent does it means you have bad architecture for your components, or something else needs to be fixed?

2) What are the cons and pros of the 2nd method?

3) Is it good to avoid them?

I am desperately trying to find answers on these questions (with explanations), It would be great if someone can provide them.

Comment: The answer highly depends what exactly you want to achieve. In my company we try to avoid subjects in general, but also ViewChild. If we'd need to choose between them, ViewChild would be our preference. Can't really explain, but Subject is more a fiddle and harder to follow.

Comment: i don't thing there is  any issue with 1 method, as you are calling method of child. its similar to using html button and calling click event of it. I see components as user added custom tags so if you use them in your ts file and call method there is nothing wrong. Note: this is my point of view

Comment: I dont go for second method specially when there is parent - child relation ship , instead i should have created service with subject and injected that service to provide communication between my component , you can refer angular.io site where making use of service is one way to provide communication between component

Answer (score 4):

Both implementations are going against the principle of separation of concerns. A child component shouldn't be having the responsibility to compute stuff for the parent component, because it means that the parent component possibly cannot work without the child.
If a function or some computed values are needed by different components, they should probably be placed in a common service to be injected in both components.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid doing either method if possible. If you find yourself needing to do this a lot then you are probably not dividing the responsibilities properly between parent and child. You should pass all the necessary data to the child so it knows when to call whatever function and if it still doesn't it's probably not that components responsibility. Having said that if you find yourself writing a pretty complex app and still needing this functionality a lot I would use something like ngrx to manage the state properly. Also if you were to use the second method you should separate the subject into a service. As for the reasoning, as an application grows in size and complexity it's very convenient to rely on a predictable flow of information and actions which is why ngrx can be useful but tbh doing the first or second method a couple times in your application probably wont kill you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use changedetection:

```
// CHILD
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: '<p>child</p>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

class ChildComponent implements onChanges{
  @Input() status: boolean;
  doSomething() {
    console.log('I am from child')
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.status) {
        this.doSomething();
    }
  }

}

// PARENT
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: '<child-component [status]="status"></child-component>',
})

class ParentComponent{

  status: boolean;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.status = true;
  }
}
```